# In C#, what is the best way to cast a generic type to its base class?

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I have the following object:

```
public class ItemChange<T> where T : MyBase
{
public DateTime When { get; set; }
public string Who { get; set; }
public T NewState;
public T OldState;
}
```

and i am trying to cast and instance of `ItemChange<T>` to `ItemChange<MyBase>` but i am getting a cast exception.

**Unable to cast object of type  . . .**

WHat is the proper way to cast a generic type to its base calss (assuming the where constraint above)

Comment: The base class of `ItemChange` is not `ItemChange<MyBase>` but `MyBase`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this directly since classes in C# do not support co-variance. You can do it with interfaces however:

```
public interface IItemChange<out T> where T : MyBase
{
    DateTime When { get; set; }
    string Who { get; set; }
    T NewState { get; }
    T OldState { get; }
}

public class ItemChange<T> : IItemChange<T> where T : MyBase
{
    public DateTime When { get; set; }
    public string Who { get; set; }
    public T NewState { get; set; }
    public T OldState { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
IItemChange<MyBase> base = new ItemChange<MySubclass>();
```

for some subclass `MySubclass` of `MyBase`.

Comment: i am not trying to case from base to subbase.  i am trying to do the other way

Comment: @leora - I'm not sure what you mean - `MySubclass` is a subclass of `MyBase`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an explicit cast operator.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace brosell
{

public class MyBase
{

}



public class ItemChange<T> where T : MyBase
{
    public DateTime When { get; set; }
    public string Who { get; set; }
    public T NewState;
    public T OldState;

    public static explicit operator ItemChange<MyBase>(ItemChange<T> i)
   {
      return new ItemChange<MyBase> { When = i.When, Who = i.Who, NewState = i.NewState, OldState = i.OldState};
   }

}

public class Sub1: MyBase
{

}

public class Sub2: MyBase
{

}

   public class HelloWorld
   {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ItemChange<Sub1> item = new ItemChange<Sub1>();


        ItemChange<MyBase> itemCasted = (ItemChange<MyBase>)item;
        }
   } 
}
```